# how to display data from MySQL database in listview in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, listview

Hello everyone I want to display data from MySQL in php to list view . I am creating a classified ads website in php. I only have to display the fields results in listview like

olx.com.pk/rawalpindi

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Syed. You should improve your question by showing what you've done so far. YOur question is too broad and looks more like a "please program that for me request". You should make it more specific.

Comment: Brother thanks I have done all programming. I will post it after sometime. Because I have finished my things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<table>` or `<div>` for your listview :

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php
      $query = mysql_query();
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         echo "<tr>$row['index1']</tr>";
         echo "<tr>$row['index2']</tr>";
   ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks man i have done it. I will show you. but i am in another problem. tell me how to apply border to table row which is in while loop